# Very new at Ruby and trying to compare an array with a nested array

Tags: ruby, each, multidimensional-array

So I am building a tic tac toe game and I am trying to pull keys from my board hash and then compare that with arrays within an array.  The issue is that the winning combos all have 3 values, but it may take a player 4 or 5 moves to win, so I want to see if those 4 or 5 values include one of the winning combos (hopefully that makes sense).  Specifically the issue is with the winner_check method, is there a way to get this method working?

```
def initialize_board
  board = {}
  (1..9).each {|position| board[position] = ' ' }
  board
end

def empty_positions(board)
  board.keys.select {|position| board[position] != 'X' && 'O'}
end

def player_turn(board)
  puts "Let's play Tic Tac Toe! Pick a position 1-9 and try to beat me."
  position = gets.chomp.to_i
  board[position] = 'X'
end

def computer_turn(board)
  position = empty_positions(board).sample
  board[position] = 'O'
end

def winner_check(board)
  winning_combos = [[1, 2, 3], 
    [4, 5, 6], 
    [7, 8, 9], 
    [1, 4, 7], 
    [2, 5, 8], 
    [3, 6, 9], 
    [1, 5, 9],
    [3, 5, 7]]
    winning_combos.each {|combo|}
      if board.select { |k,v| v == 'X' }.keys.include?(combo)
        puts "You've won! Great job!"
      if board.select { |k,v| v == 'O' }.keys.include?(combo)
        puts "Looks like the computer outsmarted you, try again!"
      elsif
        puts "Looks like you've tied, try again!"
      end
    nil
  nil
end

def game_over?(board)
  empty_positions(board) == []
end

def draw_board(board)
  puts
  puts " #{board[1]} | #{board[2]} | #{board[3]} "
  puts "---+---+---"
  puts " #{board[4]} | #{board[5]} | #{board[6]} "
  puts "---+---+---"
  puts " #{board[7]} | #{board[8]} | #{board[9]} "
  puts
end

board = initialize_board
draw_board(board)

until winner_check(board) || game_over?(board)
  player_turn(board)
  draw_board(board)
  winner_check(board)
  computer_turn(board)
  draw_board(board)
  winner_check(board)
end
```

Comment: +1 Welcome to SO, and to Ruby!

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What happens when you run the program, Please post the output. Thanks

Comment: It's great to see a newbie post such a clear question! Regarding the error, error messages need to be studied carefully, as they often contain valuable information for debugging. When you post a question that describes a situation where an exception was raised, be sure to show both the (possibly trimmed) error message and the line on which it occurred.

Comment: Your code will be easier to read, debug and maintain if you avoid replication as much as possible. Here, for example, you might define a one-line helper method `win?`: `def win?(combos, board, ch); combos.any? { |positions| positions.all? { |pos| board[pos-1] == ch } }; end`, allowing you to write `if win?(combos, board, 'X'); puts "You've won.."; elsif win?(combos, board, 'O'); puts...`. You can now easily test that method to be sure it's working and I think it reads better too. Note I employed the `Enumerable` methods, `any?` and `all?`, which is more Rubyish.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track, but you have some syntax errors:

```
winning_combos.each {|combo|}
  if board.select { |k,v| v == 'X' }.keys.include?(combo)
    puts "You've won! Great job!"
  if board.select { |k,v| v == 'O' }.keys.include?(combo)
    puts "Looks like the computer outsmarted you, try again!"
  elsif
    puts "Looks like you've tied, try again!"
  end
nil
```

On the first line, you close your block too early.  The `}` at the end of the line closes the block.

On the last line, where you have a literal `nil`, I think that's where your closing `}` should go.

You also have two `if`s in a row, should be `if`, `elsif`.

Syntax errors corrected:

```
winning_combos.each { |combo|

  if board.select { |k,v| v == 'X' }.keys.include?(combo)
    puts "You've won! Great job!"
  elsif board.select { |k,v| v == 'O' }.keys.include?(combo)
    puts "Looks like the computer outsmarted you, try again!"
  elsif
    puts "Looks like you've tied, try again!"
  end
}
```

Comment: You should show a fixed/correct sample, not just describe it. Remember, a picture is worth 1,000 words.

Comment: Thank you so much Jared!  I have fixed some of my syntax errors, but still when I run this file, I get the following error:

syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

This is what my code looks like now:

Comment: def winner_check(board)
  winning_combos = [[1, 2, 3], 
    [4, 5, 6], 
    [7, 8, 9], 
    [1, 4, 7], 
    [2, 5, 8], 
    [3, 6, 9], 
    [1, 5, 9],
    [3, 5, 7]]
    winning_combos.each do |combo|

      if board.select { |k,v| v == 'X' }.keys.include?(combo)
        puts "You've won! Great job!"
      if board.select { |k,v| v == 'O' }.keys.include?(combo)
        puts "Looks like the computer outsmarted you, try again!"
      elsif
        puts "Looks like you've tied, try again!"
      end
    end
  nil
end

Comment: Jessica, you have `if board...if board...elsif`. That needs to be `if board...elsif board...elsif`